# Error code "object of type 'closure' is not subsettable?

Tags: r, markdown, knitr

New to programming and can't seem to figure this error message out. Ran every line of code and turns out fine except for when I attempt to knit the rmd file to HTML. How can I fix this? Below are my answers to a problem set as well as the error message.

````
```{r}
dim(data)
nrow(data)
range(data$year)
range=max(2008)-min(1980)
```
```{r}
rate.actual=data$total/sum(data$VAP+data$overseas)
```

```{r}
rate.difference=rate.actual-data$ANES
mean(rate.difference)
min(rate.difference)
max(rate.difference)
plot(x=data$year,y=rate.difference)
lines(x=data$year,y=rate.difference)
```
````

> "Error in data$total:object of type 'closure' is not subsettable calls:...handle->withCallingHandlers->withVisible->eval->eval"

Comment: What data is in `data` ?

Comment: Also, do you know which "chunk" the error is coming from ?

Comment: You are trying to index an object that is not indexable. What line is giving the error

Comment: I just created `data` myself and it ran fine in rmarkdown (in RStudio).  Unless I am missing something, the problem is that you don't have `data` defined in the code above.

Comment: Generally it is unwise to name objects with the same token as an R function. Tends to provoke confusing error messages.

Comment: @42- agreed, I should have changed it in my comment.  `df` is another that is often "overwritten" (`df` is the density function for the F distribution).'

Comment: Voting to close as not reproducible.

Comment: run `dput(head(data))` and update your question with the output so we can reproduce your example.